# SQL Injection protection...2nd Half of statement does not work

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My first part of the PHPstatement updates the value accordingly in the database but the 2nd half no longer sets the cookie value, what am I doing wrong, I know its something minor:

```
    include("db_connect.php");
session_start();
$input_game = $_POST['game'];
$input_user = $_POST['email'];

//$sql = "UPDATE users_table SET Pref_Game = '" . $input_game . "' WHERE Email='" . $input_user . "'";
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users_table SET Pref_Game = ? WHERE Email= ?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $input_game, $input_user);
```

2nd half of the statement:

```
   if( $stmt->execute() ) {
$cookie_name2 = "content";
setcookie($cookie_name2,$input_game, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
} else {
    //Error
}
```

Can someone shine some light on the issue on to integrate it into the 2nd half of the statement. So it works accordingly.

Comment: $sql is null (not set) because you commented it out. So, running the query: "" will not be true in the if statement.

Comment: I agree but then when I change it to $stmt it still doesn't work hence why the 2nd half wont work and I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Why do you need to query the database for the value of a field you just updated into the database?

Comment: @MikeBrant: one possible reason do that is if there is a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger that modifies the value that the UPDATE statement is assigning to the `Pref_Game` column. Or, a long value assigned to a character column might get truncated. A query of the table gets the actual value that's stored in the column, rather than assuming that the value supplied in the previous `UPDATE` is the value that was stored.

Comment: The option Mike suggested does work.

Comment: You don't need to call **`$stmt->execute()`** twice. The first line of the "2nd half" should replace the last line of the previous block. (As I explained in my answer... "Wrap the return from `$stmt->execute()` in a conditional test.) That didn't mean that you needed to invoke the `execute()` method a second time.

Comment: I have done all suggested but the cookie value still does not update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the return from `execute()` in a conditional test. ( `execute()` returns TRUE on success and `FALSE` on failure.)

You can also use a prepared statement to run your subsequent query, for example:

```
if( $stmt->execute() ) {

   $sql="SELECT Pref_Game FROM users_table WHERE Email = ?";
   $stmt2 = $conn->prepare($sql);
   $stmt2->bind_param("s",$input_user);
   $stmt2->execute();
   $pref_game = $stmt2->fetchColumn();
   setcookie($cookie_name2,$pref_game, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
   $stmt2->close();

} else {
   //Error
}
```

NOTES:

This assumes that `Email` is unique in users_table. This example code isn't testing whether the `$stmt2->execute` returns successfully or not, you can wrap that in a conditional test, so we don't fall through to the `fetchColumn. If the query is successful, but doesn't return a row, then the`fetchColumn()` will return FALSE.

```
if( $stmt->execute() ) {

   $sql="SELECT Pref_Game FROM users_table WHERE Email = ?";
   $stmt2 = $conn->prepare($sql);
   $stmt2->bind_param("s",$input_user);
   if ( $stmt2->execute() ) {
       $pref_game = $stmt2->fetchColumn();
       setcookie($cookie_name2,$pref_game, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
   } else {
     // error executing stmt2
   }
} else {
  // error executing stmt
}
```

Comment: The above you suggested still does not get the value and update the cookie value, the value does not change at all, as this would be useful when I want to apply it when checking login parameters etc

Comment: Same issue is still persisting and the cookie value does not change with the recent changes suggested on the webpage. First part of the statement updates that value in the database without and issue the 2nd $stmt2 is not although I did expect what you suggested to work

Comment: In the updated question, it shows your code calling `$stmt->execute()` twice. The first line of the 2nd half should replace the last line from the previous block... we're just wrapping the return from `$stmt->execute()` in a conditional test.  You can `echo` or `var_dump` `$pref_game`, to see that a value is returned.

Comment: Tried everything, removed what you suggested still nothing.

Comment: @Studento919: You should be able to easily debug whether the SQL statement(s) are working, add some `echo` and/or `var_dump` to show what's happening. In the question as it was originally posted, it was pretty clear what was going on. You weren't checking the return from `$stmt->execute()`, and you were running another statement. You might want to test your `setcookie` function apart from the SQL stuff, to figure out what's happening in the code. StackOverflow is a question/answer site. It's not designed as a site for posting requests for general debugging help.

Comment: @Studento919: Please see [**http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/**](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)